# Cannot insert into table because the table already exists?

Tags: sybase

I have a user table. I want to insert data into my user table.

I have a statement:

```
SELECT columna, columnb, 
INTO my_table 
FROM my_other_table
WHERE (... conditions ...)
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL Server Error on (myserver) Error:2714 at Line:1 Message:There is already an object named 'my_table' in the database.
```

Yes, thanks Sybase. I know this. I know the table exists. I want to insert data into it.

Why is Sybase not playing nicely? :(

(Sybase isn't my forte, Oracle is. This may just be an understanding issue, or lack there of. This would never happen in Oracle...)

Comment: the way you are doing it implies the creation of the table

Answer (score 35, accepted):

SELECT ... INTO is for creating new tables.

Use INSERT ... SELECT for existing tables. eg:

```
INSERT INTO my_table 
SELECT columna, columnb, 
FROM my_other_table
WHERE (... conditions ...)
```

Comment: Oh I see... That's interesting to know. Never knew you could do that in Sybase. Cheers, Peter.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried it this way around?

```
Insert INTO my_table
SELECT columna, columnb, 
FROM my_other_table
WHERE (... conditions ...)
```

It appears that it is trying to implicitly create a new table for you called my_table.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of SYBASE but in DB2 this works for me

```
 INSERT INTO my_table
 (
      columna,
      columnb
 )
 SELECT
      columna,
      columnb
 FROM
      my_other_table
 WHERE
      (... conditions...)
```

I think its safer to specify the columns in the insert statement as well rather than assume they'll be in the same order as the select.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'existing' keyword after 'into' to insert in existing table.

```
SELECT [COLUMN LIST] INTO EXISTING [TABLE NAME]
```