# How to use set rowcount in select query

Tags: unix, sybase

I have a select query statement which will result 600k rows. When I blindly extract the result using select statement it will impact db performance. Is there an option to use Set rowcount for fetching the data? I tried the below code but it keep on resulting top 50000 rows and ended up in infinite loop.

```
#!/bin/ksh -x
trap "" 1
updrowcount=50000
while [ $updrowcount -eq 50000 ]
do
QUERY="set rowcount 50000
select subject into tempdb..extract from tablename where fldr_id=8"

runisql <<EOF > db_restenter code here
$QUERY
goenter code here
quit
EOF
updrowcount=`grep "rows affected" db_rest |cut -c2- | cut -f1 -d ' '`
done
exit
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sybase

Comment: You need some way to remember the last row you already copied to start from that row in the next iteration.

Comment: For update query set rowcount works for me. Suppose say for example if i am updating 2.3 lakhs records, I can update 50000 rows each time using set rowcount with the above code But it doesnt helps when it comes for SELECT statement. @JimmyB

Comment: I had to google: ["lakh" refers to 100000 (10e5) units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh).

Comment: Your update only works if you have a WHERE condition which discriminates already-updated rows from yet-to-process rows. - The same needs to be done for a SELECT.

Comment: Btw, you cannot `SELECT INTO` an existing table that way, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010232/cannot-insert-into-table-because-the-table-already-exists.

Answer (score 0):

If your `subject` is unique, you could try something like this:

```
set rowcount 50000

declare @subject varchar(...)
select @subject = max( subject ) from tempdb..extract

insert into tempdb..extract ( subject )
select subject 
from tablename
where fldr_id=8
and (subject > @subject OR @subject is null)
order by subject
```

Otherwise, use a unique column, e.g.

```
set rowcount 50000

declare @maxId int
select @maxId = max( id ) from tempdb..extract

insert into tempdb..extract (id, subject )
select id, subject into tempdb..extract
from tablename
where fldr_id=8
and (id > @maxId OR @maxId is null)
order by id
```

(Obviously, you'll want to use an indexed column.)